Poor boy and a woman who helps him
The movie has two main characters, a teenager (short boy, black hair) who is poor and a woman who is older, blonde hair, probably with curls. The woman brings the boy at her place to help him. Both of these 2 characters are white.
I remember one scene from this movie where the boy accidentally drops and breaks a porcelain dish in the woman's house. Than he feels guilty about it but the woman comes and breaks another dish to show him that she was not affected by it. 
Maybes: The boy can play the piano, the woman has a piano at her place. She lives in an apartment, not a house (this is not so vague anymore). The season is autumn, the characters wear thicker clothes (but not winter clothes). 
The movie is:

A Drama
In colour
Most probably from '80s-'90s
Not a cartoon (Live-action) 
In English (most likely an American movie)


Hi! Do you remember anything else about the plot? What happened in the movie outside of these 2 characters?

Sorry, I'd wish I knew more. I've seen in it my childhood, probably 15 years ago, so I can't remember anything else from the plot. All the other suggestions about the movie are sentences that start with "There might be..", but it could also be really misleading.

Thanks for replying. Vague recollections are OK too, they sometimes turn out to be right. You can definitely add those in.

ok then :)  This is what might also be: The boy can play the piano, the woman has a piano at her place. She lives in an apartment, not a house (this is not so vague anymore). The season is autumn, the characters wear thicker clothes (but not winter clothes). This is not so much from the plot, but I'll try to remember more

Thanks, added in. I thought this might be Gloria from 1980 or its remake from 1999, but can't recall the dish scene or a piano in either. It definitely sounds familiar, though.

I just checked Gloria (both versions), it is not it. Both of the characters have to be white and the boy is not that young. He is a teenager. But we are getting close to it. I will edit this in the main post

Hi! Do you remember if this was a period piece or contemporary (to 80's/90's respectively)?

@Darth Locke contemporary for 80's-90's
